# Structures or javascript/json objects in progress ABL?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

We're migrating to 11.6 and I think it's a great moment to rethink old habits and improve some concepts.

One of these things is the way we've been dealing with parameter definitions in functions and procedures.

Often times we have procedures and functions that need a lot of parameters, either inputs or outputs.  Personally, for readability and maintainability reasons, I don't like to have methods with too many parameters explicitly declared.

In order to avoid this problem and still allow a large number of parameters, we've manually implemented a key-value pair approach with a single parameter.

But there are some drawbacks with this approach:

- It's not possible to tell which parameters are needed just by inspecting
  the method signature.
- You'll always need some boilerplate code, like methods for pushing and pulling values.

So with that said, I would like to hear some others' thoughts. 
Have you ever implemented something similar?

Is there something that could work as a javascript/json object in ABL?

**Current implementation.**

```
DEFINE VARIABLE param as CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

addValue('id', '1', param).
addValue('date', STRING(TODAY), param).

RUN internalProc (INPUT param).
```

**Desired implementation**

```
param.id   = 1
param.date = TODAY

RUN internalProc (INPUT param)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are mentioning 11.6, why not use a real class based object (available since 10.1A).

yourpackage\yourparameter.cls:

```
CLASS yourpackage.yourclass: 

    DEFINE PUBLIC PROPERTY date AS DATE NO-UNDO 
    GET.
    SET. 

    DEFINE PUBLIC PROPERTY id AS INTEGER NO-UNDO 
    GET.
    SET. 

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC yourclass ():
        SUPER ().

    END CONSTRUCTOR.

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC yourclass (pid AS INTEGER, pdate AS DATE):
        SUPER ().

        ASSIGN THIS-OBJECT:id = pid
               THIS-OBJECT:date = DATE . 

    END CONSTRUCTOR.

END CLASS.
```

and the internal procedure:

```
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER poParameter AS yourpackage.yourclass NO-UNDO .
```

and the caller:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE o AS yourpackage.yourclass NO-UNDO.

o = NEW yourpackage.yourclass().
o:id = 42.
o:date = TODAY.

RUN internalProc (o) .
```

alternative caller:

```
RUN internalProc (NEW yourpackage.yourclass (1, TODAY)) .
```

The ABL provides full OO capabilities from 10.1A on and that can be mixed nicely with procedural code. And parameter objects (structs) is a great way to get started with a few inital classes in legacy code.

Comment: This is an option, though it could add too much complexity to a simple task. I'll keep that in mind. I just check it here about Dictionary from .net . Do you know it this could do the trick?

Comment: Where do you see complexity?

Comment: Maybe complexity is not the way to put this. But in a large app I'd need hundreds of classes like this. Because, you know, parameters are in everywhere.

Comment: Sure! But the benefit is compile time verification. You can certainly build a dictionary in ABL, but who"d guarantee that no one in the team uses a member with a typo?

Comment: Here's a link a some list and dictionary classes in ABl https://github.com/consultingwerk/ListsAndEnumSamples

Comment: Thank you Mike. I'll take a look.

Comment: But just for the record... for parameters I really prefer specific types :-)